# How to manage activeFocus with QtQuick TableView (Qt5)

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I want to navigate in a TableView (1 column, n rows) using key pressed events (next cell, previous cell, 10 cells before, 10 cells after, etc...). I tried to use an ItemSelectionModel (as per the following code) but I am surprised that I need to force the active focus on the targeted element. Is it expected? Is there a better way to do?

```
TableView {              
            id: tableView
            ItemSelectionModel {
                id: ism
                model: tableView.model
                onCurrentChanged: {
                    // if I uncomment this line, I get the activeFocus on the correct item
                   // tableView.itemAtCell(0, current.row).forceActiveFocus()
                }
            }

            delegate:
               ....

            }
            model: TableModel {
                id: tvm
                TableModelColumn { display: "name" }

                rows: [
                    {
                        "name": "cat"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "dog"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "bird"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "fish"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "velociraptor"
                    }
                ]
            }

            Keys.onPressed: {
                // calculate index
                ....
                 ism.setCurrentIndex(model.index(index,0), ItemSelectionModel.Current)
            }

           

        }
```